# Distribution of zeros

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose $f(z) = P(z)e^{Q(z)}$ where $P,Q$ are real polynomials. What is the number of non-real zeros of $f^{(k)}$ as $k$ increases?

We know that $f''$ has $\geq m$ zeros where $m$ depends on $Q(z)$.

Comment: This could be interesting -- it might be worth adding some motivation, as well as your state of knowledge about the problem, however.

Comment: I can't edit - someone should put a $k$ between "as" and "increases". 

Answer (score 3):

Just some hints. The functions $f^{\,(k)}$ have the same zeros of the polynomials $P_k:=f^{\,(k)}\exp(-Q)$, that satisfy  $P_0:=P$ and $P_{k+1}=P_k'+P_kQ'$. In particular $P_k$ has degree $\deg(P)+k\left(\deg(Q)-1\right)$, and this is also the total number of zeros of $f^{\,(k)}$. They may be all real: for instance if $Q:=-x^2$ and $P:=1$ one finds the Hermite polynomials, that are orthogonal, hence have all zeros real and simple.

Answer (score 0):

One could use the level sets $\{z \in H^{+}: \text{Im} Q(z) = 0 \}$ to count non-real zeros of the derivatives of $f(z)$ where $Q$ is the Newton's method function for $f$.